# How to query for a nested date range in Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

Ok, here's my data:

```
"stats" : [
    {
        "campaign_id" : "some_id",
        "log_id" : "some_id",
        "agent" : "some_id",
        "office" : "some_id",
        "hq" : "some_name",
        "seller" : "some_name",
        "status" : "live",
        "phases" : [
            {
                "phase" : "main_phase",
                "banners" : [
                    {
                        "banner_id" : "some_id_same_as_below",
                        "split_var" : "light",
                        "reports" : [
                            {
                                "date" : "2016-11-25",
                                "banner" : "some_id_same_as_above",
                                "cost" : "0.231",
                                "impressions" : 14,
                                "clicks" : 0
                            },
          ...
```

And I need to query the database for all reports:

```
"reports" : [
{
    "date" : "2016-11-25",
    "banner" : "some_id_same_as_above",
    "cost" : "0.231",
    "impressions" : 14,
    "clicks" : 0
},
```

For the `"date" : "2016-11-25"` within a date range. For the date range I have this:

```
start_month = DateTime.current.beginning_of_month - 1.month
end_month = DateTime.current.end_of_month - 1.month
```

Which gives me start and end of the previous month, which is right. How can I search for all documents that have reports (the nested values inside stats, phases, etc) that falls within this range?

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

It has been suggested to change the way the data is inserted into the db, but unfortunately I have no control on how the data is inserted (done by a third party service/API).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the dates as standard Date objects instead of formatted strings, which MongoDB stores in ISODate format, for instance:

```
db.collection.insert({date: new Date()});
```

will have a field like:

```
{ "date" : ISODate("2016-11-15T15:50:15.167Z") }
```

Then you can query by date range (Use the $and operator if you need to query between two ranges or the second statement may override the first)

Such as:

```
// Return all documents in collection with a date between 11-1-2016 and 12-1-2016
db.collection.find({
    $and: [
        { date: { $gte: ISODate("2016-11-01T00:00:00.000Z") } }, 
        { date: { $lt: ISODate("2016-12-01T00:00:00.000Z") } }
    ]
})
```

EDIT: In case you cannot modify your collections, you could do a regex  style search...

For instance:

```
db.collection.find({
    "stats.phases.banners.reports.date": /2016-11/
});
```

will return all documents for November 2016 since it matches on all strings containing "2016-11"

EDIT AGAIN:

Here is a solution using the aggregation framework to return the documents in the format you mentioned above i.e.

```
{
    "reports" : { 
        "date" : "2016-11-23", 
        "banner" : ObjectId("58404a9450b5412e92ebbb97"), 
        "cost" : "0.231", 
        "impressions" : 14, 
        "clicks" : 0 
    } 
},
{ 
    "reports" : { 
        "date" : "2016-11-25", 
        "banner" : ObjectId("58404a9450b5412e92ebbb97"), 
        "cost" : "0.231", 
        "impressions" : 14, 
        "clicks" : 0 
    } 
}
```

Note you have to do a lot of unwinds due to your heavily nested array structure...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$stats" },
    { $unwind: "$stats.phases" },
    { $unwind: "$stats.phases.banners" },
    { $unwind: "$stats.phases.banners.reports" },
    { $match: { "stats.phases.banners.reports.date": /2016-11/ } },
    { $project: { _id: 0, reports: "$stats.phases.banners.reports" } }
])
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to store `date` fields in as ISODate objects and then you can use comparison operators like `$lt`, `$lte`, `$gt`, `$gte`, etc.
Here is how to insert data:

```
db.test.insert({
  "stats": [
    {
      "campaign_id": "some_id",
      "log_id": "some_id",
      "agent": "some_id",
      "office": "some_id",
      "hq": "some_name",
      "seller": "some_name",
      "status": "live",
      "phases": [
        {
          "phase": "main_phase",
          "banners": [
            {
              "banner_id": "some_id_same_as_below",
              "split_var": "light",
              "reports": [
                {
                  "date": ISODate("2016-11-25T00:00:00.0Z"),
                  "banner": "some_id_same_as_above",
                  "cost": "0.231",
                  "impressions": 14,
                  "clicks": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Following is the query to find documents whose `stats.phases.banners.reports.date` is between 25 Nov 2016 to 15 Dec 2016.

```
db.test.find({"stats.phases.banners.reports.date": {$lt: ISODate("2016-11-25T00:00:00.0Z"), $gt: ISODate("2016-12-25T00:00:00.0Z")}})
```

Comment: are you sure this is working example?  please explain how this answer work?